# Is the decomposition in BCNF?

Tags: bcnf

I've got a database with a scheme R with the attributes: `R(ABCDE)`, with the
`FD`'s: `A -> BC, C -> D, D -> E`. I've decomposed the scheme into `Relation 1: ABC`
and `relation 2: CDE`. Is it okay to say that these two relations are in BCNF and are lossless when they join each other?

Answer (score 0):

I think No.
Since, has the FD C->D, D->E,
the relation 2 still not in BCNF.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency D->E in relation 2 still violates both 3NF and BCNF.  You need to further decompose relation 2 into (CD;C->D), (DE;D->E).